# Why can't set middle ticks in the right y-axis?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Import all modules needed when to plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Create data to plot with:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'close':np.random.uniform(19, 36, 200)})
```

Prepare figure and axes object and plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index,df['close'])
```

Calculate all min and max for x-axis,yleft-axis,yright_axis

```
xmin,xmax = df.index[0],df.index[-1]
p_min,p_max = min(df['close']),max(df['close'])
c_min,c_max = 100*p_min/p_max,100
```

Create right axis with secondary_yaxis method:

```
t_price_change = lambda t_p: 100* t_p/p_max
t_change_price = lambda t_c: t_c*p_max /100    
ax_right = ax.secondary_yaxis("right", functions=(t_price_change, t_change_price))
```

Create ticks for x-axis,yleft-axis,yright_axis

```
ticks_x = np.append(ax.get_xticks(), (xmin,xmax))
ticks_yleft =  np.append(ax.get_yticks(), (p_min,p_max))
ticks_yright = np.append(ax_right.get_yticks(), (c_min,c_max))
```

set ticks for x-axis,yleft-axis,yright_axis

```
ax.set_xticks(ticks_x)
ax.set_yticks(ticks_yleft)
ax_right.set_yticks(ticks_yright)
```

Set the range

```
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(p_min, p_max)
ax_right.set_ylim(c_min, c_max)
```

show the graph:

```
plt.show()
```

[image]

You see that no middle ticks for the right y-axis,how can add some with code?

Comment: What are you expecting there? What should the ticks and ticklabels be? If you print `t_price_change`, it is a function and if you print `ax_right.get_yticks()` before appending, it is just 0, 0.2, ...1. So, you need to define the labels. As data is plotted against ax_left, nothing is currently plotted against ax_right... makes sense?

Comment: How can add more ticks on the rigth y-axis automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is because nothing is really plotted on the secondary y axis, the ticks are 0,0.2,...1. Adding ~54 and 100 and then setting the y_lim is removing the other ticks. To add additional ticks to the secondary y axis AND keep the existing ticks (c_min and c_max), you need to change the line where you are creating `ticks_yright` to bewlo...

```
ticks_yright = np.round(np.linspace(c_min, c_max, 5), 1)
```

Note that `5` above will give you 5 ticks. Change it to increase or decrease the number of ticks. This should give you a plot like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to create ticks for the right y-axis:

```
def get_ticks_yright(c_min,c_max):
    result = [c_min,c_max]
    n = int((c_max - c_min)// 10)
    if n > 1:
        for item in range(1,n+1):
            result.append(10*(c_min//10) + item*10)
    return result
```

With almost same code as above:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'close':np.random.uniform(19, 36, 200)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index,df['close'])
xmin,xmax = df.index[0],df.index[-1]
p_min,p_max = min(df['close']),max(df['close'])
c_min,c_max = 100*p_min/p_max,100
t_price_change = lambda t_p: 100* t_p/p_max
t_change_price = lambda t_c: t_c*p_max /100
ax_right = ax.secondary_yaxis("right", functions=(t_price_change, t_change_price))
ticks_x = np.append(ax.get_xticks(), (xmin,xmax))
ticks_yleft =  np.append(ax.get_yticks(), (p_min,p_max))
ticks_yright = get_ticks_yright(c_min,c_max)
ax.set_xticks(ticks_x)
ax.set_yticks(ticks_yleft)
ax_right.set_yticks(ticks_yright)
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(p_min, p_max)
ax_right.set_ylim(c_min,c_max)
plt.show()
```

The highest price is 100,it is more meaningful to add 90,80,70 and so on in ticks.
[image]